# Entry point for MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have created new emty project. Then have added cpp and header hello world files taken from Jeff Prosise 'Programming Windows with MFC' book. Have set `Use of MFC` to `Use MFC in a Shared DLL`

Got error `entry point must be defined` 
How to fix this problem?

CPP:

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include "Hello.h"

CMyApp myApp;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CMyApp member functions

BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance ()
{
    m_pMainWnd = new CMainWindow;


   m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow (m_nCmdShow);
    m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow ();
    return TRUE;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CMainWindow message map and member functions

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP (CMainWindow, CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT ()
END_MESSAGE_MAP ()

CMainWindow::CMainWindow ()
{
    Create (NULL, _T ("The Hello Application"));
}

void CMainWindow::OnPaint ()
{
    CPaintDC dc (this);

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect (&rect);

    dc.DrawText (_T ("Hello, MFC"), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
}
```

H:

```
class CMyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance ();
};

class CMainWindow : public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    CMainWindow ();

protected:
    afx_msg void OnPaint ();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP ()
};
```

Comment: You missed your main function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to tell compiler to use `WinMain` (which is provided by MFC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akdx0603.aspx) instead of `main` as an entry point.

Right click project, select `Properties`, and navigate to `Linker` -> `System` -> `SubSystem`. Change `SubSystem` to `Windows`.